# Select a data-id using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery I want to be able to select the data-rating from the radio buttons when the user clicks on one of the buttons?

```
<label class="ratingStar"><input type="radio" name="spotRating" id="_1of5" data-rating="1" data-spot-id="1" class="rating-system" /></label>
<label class="ratingStar"><input type="radio" name="spotRating" id="_1of5" data-rating="2" data-spot-id="2" class="rating-system" /></label>
```

I have tried the following

```
$(".ratingStar").on("click", function(){

    selected_rating = $('input', $this).data("rating");
    selected_id = $('input', $this).data("id");


    console.log(selected_rating)

});
```

Comment: You've told us what you've tried, now tell us what's wrong with it. What does it do? Why isn't that correct? What should it actually do?

Comment: Your two buttons have the same id, that's invalid html.

Comment: `$this` is undefined. That's the whole reason your code isn't working. That should have been very clear had you gone to the console, unless you have other similar functions where you failed to use the `var` keyword that may have set a global `$this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, there was no id in the element so i guessed you meant data-spot-id

```
$(".ratingStar").on("click", function(){
    selected_rating = $('input', this).data("rating");
    selected_id = $('input', this).data("spot-id"); //Changed to spot-id


    console.log(selected_rating)

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The below will work:

```
$(".ratingStar").on("click", function () {
    selected_rating = $('input', $(this)).data("rating");
    selected_id = $('input', $(this)).data("spot-id");
    console.log(selected_rating)
});
```

**EDIT 1:** Actually it works with even `data("id")` if we modify the `$this` to just `this` or `$(this)`.

For example, the below works. Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/a2xrU/) for a demo.

```
$(".ratingStar").on("click", function () {
    selected_rating = $('input', this).data("rating");
    selected_id = $('input', this).data("id"); // data("spot-id") also works
    console.log(selected_rating)
});
```

**EDIT 2:** Quoting Anthony Grist's comment.

> The context (that **second argument**) can be either a **DOM element** or a
>   **jQuery object**. `this` is a **DOM element**, so you can pass it directly:
>   `$('input', this)`. Doing `$(this)` calls the jQuery function, and creates
>   a **new jQuery object** simply containing this - since you don't need to
>   do that (passing this works just fine) you should avoid doing so

Based on the above the answer provided under **EDIT 1** is the preferred option.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to be doing `$(this)` (and at least a couple of reasons **not** to do it).

Comment: Please explain me so that I can understand them and stop using it. I guess that might add more value to the answer also. Side note, it works only this way in fiddle `$this` did not work.

Comment: The context (that second argument) can be either a DOM element or a jQuery object. `this` is a DOM element, so you can pass it directly: `$('input', this)`. Doing `$(this)` calls the jQuery function, and creates a new jQuery object simply containing `this` - since you don't need to do that (passing `this` works just fine) you should avoid doing so.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Thanks a lot mate. I will update it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access the data by referring to the attributes, using the [.attr() method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$(".ratingStar").on("click", function(){
    selected_rating = $('input', $this).attr("data-rating");
    selected_id = $('input', $this).attr("data-spot-id");
    console.log(selected_rating);
});
```